# Copper-free Click Chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Classic click chemistry, also known as Huisgen 1,3-Dipolar Cycloaddition, is the azide-alkyne cycloaddition in the presence of copper as catalyst. 
[image]

The toxic metal used as catalyst precluded its application in medicine until the recent introduction of copper-free click chemistry. 
It involves the reaction between cyclooctyne (azadibenzocyclooctyne) and azide, which proceeds like an explosion to give a single product without the presence of a toxic metal as catalyst.

[image]

Why is a catalyst unnecessary for this reaction?

Comment: Because it's faster? Asking why it's faster is rather a complicated question which I suspect nobody will be able to answer.

Comment: @bon It's mean there is no answer to that question,

Comment: The short answer to your question is that instead of increasing the reaction rate by providing an alternate reaction pathway (lowering the reaction's activation energy) with a catalyst, the catalyst-free version uses a higher energy starting material, due to the ring strain from the triple bond and electron-withdrawing groups, which lowers the activation energy by increasing the energy of the starting point. I'm not familiar with the precise mechanisms involved and the design of different starting materials, so I will leave it to others to give a more complete answer.

Comment: @MichaelD.M.Dryden It mean due to strain from the triple bond lowers the activation energy, and  reaction happened even in the absence of catalyst.

Comment: @N.ALodhi: yes, the activation energy is lowered by increasing the energy of the starting material (i.e. it is less stable). If you use a catalyst, you lower the energy of the transition state(s).